# Conditioning reading from serial port

Tags: python, while-loop, serial-port, conditional-statements, pyserial

I'm writing this code to read and fill a .txt from serial communication. I'm using a counter that increments after each reading, but it is not enough. I want the reading to stop when the last line is either `" Test completed and passed "` or `" Test completed and failed "`. Below is the part of code that I wrote:

```
 **    timeout = 0
#open log file
f = open(Test_name+'_log.txt','a')
while (timeout < 90000):####
    # Read line from uart
    data=ser.readline().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    #convert data to string
    data=str(data.lower())
    # Remove \r from data 
    data = data.replace('\r','')
    print(data)
    # Write data inside log file 
    f.write(data)
    # Increment timer
    timeout=timeout+1
    print(timeout)
    if data.lower().startswith(' Test completed and passed ',' Test completed and failed '):
        break
        f.close()
        ser.close()
        print('out',timeout)
# Close log file
f.close()
# Close serial port
ser.close()
```

Comment: `while not data.lower().startswith(('test completed and passed', 'test completed and failed'))`?

Comment: mighri hajer: You could use `startswith()` as @Olvin is suggests to do a conditional `break` in the middle of your `while` loop, which will terminate the loop at that point.

Comment: ... or you can initialize `data` as empty string before loop start and use condition I've provided in first comment.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: The problem with your suggestions is that they both — as presented — eliminate the `timeout` checking.

Comment: @martineau, yes, you're right, and I've done that intentionally, because that's not a timeout at all, it's more limit of read attempts, which looks like temporary condition just for testing. If `Serial` have been initialized with `timeout = None` then `readline()` will wait until data arrives and I doubt that it's possible to get 1 million of separate messages via serial at all.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Good points. The OP is vague about how what they're doing "is not enough" — perhaps it means not enough to stop the loop.

Comment: @martineau my problem is that the timeout ends before the actual communication that's why i put it up to 1000000 but now it's taking too long ...that's why i want to add the check of the last line to the loop...

Comment: mighri hajer: So, from my previous comment(s), do you now know how to do that?

Comment: @martineau no! it won't break out of the loop, i updated the code if you could check it out

Comment: It could simply be that no line starts with either of those strings. It seems a little odd that they both include a leading and trailing space character, so unless a line starts with ***exactly*** one of those two strings, then the `break` will not occur. Also note that the lines immediately after the `break`, indented at the same level, will never execute — so remove them (they are not needed anyway).

Comment: @mighrihajer, `data.lower().startswith(' Test completed and passed ',' Test completed and failed ')` can't be truth, because: **1)** You pass two arguments instead of *tuple* with two items; **2)** Strings you pass to `startswith()` contains uppercase letters while data have been translated to lowercase before. You can copy correct condition from first comment to this post.